# How to Post "multipart/form-data" Form and get the Text field values from the Node.js server?

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, content-type

Í'm trying to upload a file using multer. I can upload the file but somehow unable to get the text box values inside the form with the content/type
"multipart/form-data".

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <div class="file-field input-field">
        <div class="btn grey">
          <span>File</span>
          <input name="myImage" type="file" multiple="multiple"> 
        </div>
        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
          <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
        </div>        
      </div>
      <div ><input type="text" name="test"/></div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

How can I get the value of the textbox

```
<div ><input type="text" name="test"/></div>
```

using body.parser?
when I try

```
const {test} = req.body;
```

it gives an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include body parser to your node server:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());       
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
```

Then you should have access to form data in body i.e. `req.body.test`.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more information.

Answer (score 1):

use `app.use(express.json())` instead since bodyParser was added back to Express in release 4.16.0, because people wanted it bundled with Express. That means you don't have to use `bodyParser.json()` anymore if you are on the latest release. You can use `express.json()` instead.