# How to get text value from multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multipartform-data, multer

I'm building a React app, and one of the components is creating a FormData object with two fields - one is a file and the other is a string. The FormData is being sent as a PUT method to an express route, and its type is multipart/form-data because there's a file to upload. There I need to get the string valie from the form (called path), then use multer/multer-s3 to upload the file to AWS S3 to the specified path.

I'm stuck on how to do this. I wasn't able to find an answer on how to retrieve a text field from a multipart request. I did see [How to Post "multipart/form-data" Form and get the Text field values from the Node.js server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55434721/how-to-post-multipart-form-data-form-and-get-the-text-field-values-from-the-no) and several similar suggestions, however the suggested answer did not work for me.

On the body-parser website, it says "This does not handle multipart bodies" - so that also means that bodyParser.urlencoded wouldn't help in my case.

React component:

```
const path = `/somepathhere/`;
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('path', path)

// call API handler
```

apiActions.js:

```
const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: "PUT", 
  body: formData
})
```

server.js:

```
// other code taken out for brevity

// middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// other code taken out for brevity

app.put('/api/uploadToS3', (req, res) => {
  const path = '';

  const storage = multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET,
    contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
    cacheControl: 'max-age=31536000',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, path + file.originalname)
    }
  })

  const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
  }).any();

  upload(req,res,function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.end("Error uploading file.");
    } else {
       res.end("File has been uploaded");
    }
  });
});
```

If there is a better way to handle this, I would also like to know. The end goal is that the file should be uploaded to an S3 path dynamically determined in the React app. I tried sending an object with formData and path like such:

```
const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: "PUT", 
    body: {formData: formData, path: path}
  })
```

But that gave the error: `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`. Trying to add headers to the fetch request likewise gave various errors.